# how to make all threads wait one

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to start a thread that sends 200 different threads a string (url) and they start. The first thread then stops. When this url returns a 404 error, all threads must stop, and the first thread needs to start. How do I organize it? Thanks.

Sorry for my english. And I hope you understand me)

How I start threads:

```
Thread[] thr;
int good_delete;
static object locker = new object();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = true;
    decimal value = numericUpDown1.Value;
    int i = 0;
    int j = (int)(value);
    thr = new Thread[j];
    for (; i < j; i++)
    {
        thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
        thr[i].IsBackground = true;
        thr[i].Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending different url to each thread?

Comment: If you have 200 threads you are doing something wrong.

Comment: You should provide more code with details. I need to know the way which is used to manipulate threads.

Comment: Don't do that with public servers.

Comment: You should consider, how many thread you want? If there are 61 urls then why you have 200 threads, you can look WaitHandle.WaitAll, this article will guide you to do so, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n

Comment: So code is bad, you should redesign it. Lets start, please describe the target goal.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh I need start 1 thread, the return value of which (the string with url) will send to 200 threads. 200 threads send Post requests to this url and when one of these 200 threads get that url returns 404 error, all 200 threads must stop and loop starts from the beginning.

Comment: Please don't think about threads, I want to know a goal of the task.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method for this. For more info look at [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx).

**Edit** your code might look like:

```
int j = (int)(value);
thr = new Thread[j];
ManualResetEvent[] manualEvents = new ManualResetEvent[j];
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    manualEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(go), manualEvents[i]);
}
WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualEvents);
```

After that you should set event in your `go` method:

```
private void go(object state)
{
    //put your code here
    ((ManualResetEvent)state).Set();
}
```

Also notice that maximum number of `WaitHandle` objects passed to the `WaitAll` method is 64 so you have to manually split the sources.

Good luck!

Comment: Typo, WaitHangle should be WaitHandle

Comment: WaitAll have a limite to the number of the event handlers

Answer (score 0):

Any way to achive your goal you should use Join method of the thread object

```
  for (; i < j; i++)
  {
    thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
    thr[i].IsBackground = true;
    thr[i].Start();
  }

  for (; i < j; i++)
  {
    thr[i].Join();
  }
```